# iOS Daily Local Push Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to execute a `UILocalNotification` at **9:00 AM** every day, forever, as long as the app is open. The closest thing I've found is this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
notification.alertBody = @"It's been 24 hours.";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

However, this code only executes a `UILocalNotification` once in 24 hours, not at a specified time. I've been looking into utilizing `NSDate` somehow, but have been getting no where.

The code will be executing in the `AppDelegate` in the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. If someone were to open the application and place it in the background at **8:59 AM**, the `UILocalNotification` would still execute at **9:00 AM**.

An `NSDateComponent` won't work with this because I would have to declare a year, month, and day, but I want to execute this `UILocalNotification` every day without having to edit the code.

Comment: Does the code snippet actually fire the alert EVERY DAY or only once, 24 hours from now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to find the NEXT time that 9am occurs, and set the local notification to fire at that time:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:9];
// Gives us today's date but at 9am
NSDate *next9am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
if ([next9am timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
    // If today's 9am already occurred, add 24hours to get to tomorrow's
    next9am = [next9am dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
}

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = next9am;
notification.alertBody = @"It's been 24 hours.";
// Set a repeat interval to daily
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: Using `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` could bring some misbehavior: for example, if the code is run the day of the time-shift for daylight saving time, tomorrow alarm would fire at the wrong date. It is much better to use `NSDateComponents`. See my similar answer below if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has two problems:

1. Obtain the right NSDate for the **next** fire date.
2. Setup the local notification in order to fire every 24 hours

Here is a snippet:

```
// 1st: find next fire date, using NSDateComponents

NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents * components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

// Components will now contain information about current hour and minute, day, month and year.

// Do your calculation in order to setup the right date. Note that components reflect user timezone.
// For example, skip to the next day if current time is after 9:00:
if (components.hour >= 9) {
    components.day += 1;
}

// Now fix the components for firing time, for example 9:00.
components.hour = 9;
components.minute = 0;

NSDate * fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"Notification will fire at: %@", fireDate);


// 2nd: Schedule local notification with repetitions:

UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = fireDate;
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit; // Here is the trick

notification.alertBody = @"It's been 24 hours.";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `repeatInterval` before scheduling the notification

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
```