# Schedule UILocalNotification everyday at specific time

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I am using below piece of code to schedule a localnotification at specific time. But the notification is repeating for every minute instead of after one day. Whether i have missed any notification settings. My timezone is **(Asia/Calcutta (IST) offset 19800)** and using iPhone 4s.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{     
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:now]; 
    [components setHour:12];
    [components setMinute:00];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notification.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"U got notification!!!"];
    // notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification]; 
}
```

Comment: use repeatinterval property of localnotification localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;you also get help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748062/ios-daily-local-push-notifications

Answer (score 15):

You should specify `repeatInterval`.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{     
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:now]; 
    [components setHour:12];
    [components setMinute:00];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notification.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [notification setAlertBody:@"U got notification!!!"];
    // notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification]; 
}
```

Comment: @[Sviatoslav Yakymiv] it means notification will be triggered at 12:00 daily?

Comment: @Nitesh yes. It will

Comment: How can I repeat notification based on different times in my array to set automatically notify me daily on given time in array when the date is the index of an array I have a moths array

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv What if I have hour array and minute array and want to repeat daily Have a look at this question plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857236/trigger-local-notifications-automatically-daily-on-dynamic-time-given-in-arrays